# Converting Java Parcel creator code to Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to convert my Parcel Creator code from Java to Kotlin. The auto code converter fails at this and I'm not sure how to resolve it. The code I'm converting is:

```
public static final Creator<Save> CREATOR = new Creator<Save>() {

    @Override
    public Save[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Save[size];
    }

    @Override
    public Save createFromParcel(Parcel incoming) {
        return new Save(incoming);
    }
};
```

I end up with this:

```
val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Save> = object : Parcelable.Creator<Save> {

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Save> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }

    override fun createFromParcel(incoming: Parcel): Save {
        return Save(incoming)
    }
}
```

which gives an error saying 'Type inference failed' for arrayOfNulls(size). I have tried changing it to Save(size) but that doesn't work either. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayOfNulls` will return an array of nullable elements, `Array<Save?>` in this case. You should change your function's return type to match that.

```
override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Save?> {
    return arrayOfNulls(size)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://github.com/nekocode/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin-kotlin) plugin to do Parcelable, just suggestion, I never tried but come across while googling.